# Infrastructure to enable integration of bounded contexts with messaging and web services

Tags: domain-driven-design, bounded-contexts

On my first foray into integration of systems have I identified the following bounded contexts:

1. Invoicing
2. Subscriptions
3. Collections

Specifically for the Collections bounded context 'suspends overdue accounts' feature, we would:

1. Get a list of overdue invoices from Invoicing
2. Send suspension notice to user (internal e-mailer service)
3. Send suspension requested to Subscriptions bounded context

I understand how a blocking web service could be used to integrate the bounded contexts, but I can see this would bring issues in the event the remote service is down.

I am aware of message buses, but not sure how we would integrate with a message strategy:

Would each context contain a local read-model of external bounded context (listen for events from external bounded contexts when they are adding/deleting entities, and correlating via a unique ID)?

If using messages, do we literally build up a local copy of the entity (with fields of use for the local context) from the remote context of interest? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: MEssage Driven Architecture, more exactly the Domain Events pattern is for this problem. A bounded context will sotre only relevant data for its own context i.e not a copy of what other BC considers to be the model. Your 'question' is too localized and quite debatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scenario, you can employ an [event-driven architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_architecture) and avoid storing data locally. In order to suspend overdue accounts, you can have the Invoicing BC publish an event indicating that an invoice is past due. The Collections and Subscriptions BC would subscribe to that event and invoke the required behaviors. From the perspective of the Invoicing BC, you'd have a [domain event](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/04/08/strengthening-your-domain-domain-events/) called something like InvoiceBecamePastDue and it would be published externally via message bus.

In this case, it doesn't seem like you need a local copy. There are instances however where a local copy of data is required in which case you would maintain the local copy using published events.

Comment: That is *very* useful thanks. What if we wanted to define a CollectionStrategy (on a per customer account basis) that would define actions to take (i.e 10 days before, send reminder. On invoice date email reminder. On 3 days over email and SMS. 5 days over suspend), would we publish InvoiceIsDaysOverdue for every invoice from Invoices, or would it be better for Collections to maintain its own list of invoice due (via events or via a GetInvoicesDue webservice)?

Comment: If it is the responsibility of the Collections BC to send due and past due notices, then have to subscribe to the InvoiceCreated event (and InvoiceRemoved if applicable). It would then store the due date and based on that date you can trigger various events such as "due in a week", or "past due".

Comment: The Invoicing BC is a cloud based accounting system (which could change in the future). I will write some middleware that polls the invoicing app and generates events from it. Not sure what this middleware architecture would be called, but for sure it will solve a lot of issues and nasty error checking code. You obviously have a great knack of identifying domain concepts - any online links to read-up and learn from or is this just a matter of experience?

Comment: For an EDA take on domain modelling take look at - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/architecture/aa699424.aspx. Also for DDD in general - http://www.amazon.com/Implementing-Domain-Driven-Design-Vaughn-Vernon/dp/0321834577

Comment: A follow up query, if we subscribe to InvoiceCreated events and store the due date inside the Collections BC, would these dates be stored in an a Entity Root inside the Collections BC or a read model?